# Why torch.nn.transformer does not have positional encoding module?

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I find that the [original implementation](https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch/blob/master/transformer/Layers.py) of transformer contains the positional encoding module. But in the [implementation of pytorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py#L16), it does not.

Why?